# Linked Server Setup Error - SSL Provider: The client and server cannot communicate, because

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, linked-server, ssl, tls-1.2

I am trying to setup a linked server and ending up with the following error.
Error:
`SSL Provider: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.`

[image]

Environment: 
Linked server is being created on
`Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU8) (KB4013104) - 11.0.6594.0 (X64)  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)`
`Windows Server 2012 Standard`

IISCrypto shows these values
[image]

Source Server:
`Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64) 
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`
`Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise`

IISCrypto shows these values
[image]

I gave up resolving this issue for a while now.
Could someone please assist me on this?
I need to create this Linked server!! What am I doing wrong all these days?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure both servers have support for TLS 1.2.

The following table, taken from [the Microsoft Support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server), shows when TLS 1.2 support was added to each particular SQL Server version:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║           SQL Server release            ║    First build that supports TLS 1.2     ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ SQL Server 2014 SP1                     ║ 12.0.4439.1                              ║
║ SQL Server 2014 SP1 GDR                 ║ 12.0.4219.0                              ║
║ SQL Server 2014 RTM                     ║ 12.0.2564.0                              ║
║ SQL Server 2014 RTM GDR                 ║ 12.0.2271.0                              ║
║ SQL Server 2012 SP3 GDR                 ║ 11.0.6216.27                             ║
║ SQL Server 2012 SP3                     ║ 11.0.6518.0                              ║
║ SQL Server 2012 SP2 GDR                 ║ 11.0.5352.0                              ║
║ SQL Server 2012 SP2                     ║ 11.0.5644.2                              ║
║ SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3                  ║ 10.50.6542.0                             ║
║ SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 GDR (IA-64 only) ║ 10.50.4047.0                             ║
║ SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 (IA-64 only)     ║ 10.50.4344.0                             ║
║ SQL Server 2008 SP4                     ║ 10.0.6547.0                              ║
║ SQL Server 2008 SP3 GDR (IA-64 only)    ║ 10.0.5545.0                              ║
║ SQL Server 2008 SP3 (IA-64 only)        ║ 10.0.5896.0                              ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

If you have a version of SQL Server prior to those listed in the above, you should apply the latest service pack and cumulative update to enable TLS 1.2 support.

https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com and https://sqlserverupdates.com/ contain excellent resources detailing where to get the latest updates for SQL Server.